# Header.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c

I'm trying to link my c files and header files in compilation, but get the following error:
`fatal error: header1.h: No such file or directory #include <header1.h>`

The problem is, I have included the header file using `#include <header1.h>` in each c file, and compiled using the command `gcc header1.h file1.c file2.c main.c -Wall -std=c99` But still gives me the error in every c file. I've included the top of my code from each file below.

header1.h:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h> 

typedef struct microtreat{
    int id;                 
    char user[51];          
    char text[141];         
   
    struct microtreat*next;  
}treat;
```

main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <header1.h>
```

file 1:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <header1.h>
```

file 2:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <header1.h>
```

How do I fix this error? Thanks

Comment: Change `#include <header1.h>` to `#include "header1.h"`

Comment: to explain: <> indicates a file in system path (like stdlib.h) but header1.h is most likely local to your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
#include "header1.h"
```

when you use the <> include. the pre processor search's for the header in certain paths but if you want to include file in the directory of your c files you should use include ""

if you want to include header file in other directory you can compile it with the directory which the header is in like so:

```
gcc some_compilation_flags name_of_c_file_to_compile.c -iquote /path/to/the/header/directory
```

the flag -iquote say to the compiler to include this directory to find the include file in it

Comment: `"HEADER1.h"` -> `"header1.h"`. Not every file system is case-insensitive. Always use the same character-cases as in the filename.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of including headers in C/C++.
`#include <header.h>` looks for the header in the system path
`#include "header.h"` starts looking from the local folder of the file including the header

Here there is a much more detailed explanation
[What is the difference between #include <filename> and #include "filename"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593/what-is-the-difference-between-include-filename-and-include-filename)